# .NET Core 1.1 app with PCL, unable to build on Team services

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, msbuild

I have following projects on solution and this works perfectly fine on my local.

[image]

However when I check code in Team service and create build it fails.

`mainconsole.csproj`

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>    
    <PackageTargetFallback>portable-net45+win8</PackageTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility" Version="1.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\business\business.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\portableextensibility\portableextensibility.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\portablelibrary\portablelibrary.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Build tasks:

1. command line - tool `dotnet`, argument - `restore`
2. command line -    tool `dotnet`, argument - `build`

Build fails:

> d:\a\3\s\portablelibrary\portablelibrary.csproj(43,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.4\Microsoft\Portable\v4.5\Microsoft.Portable.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
>   d:\a\3\s\portableextensibility\portableextensibility.csproj(42,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.4\Microsoft\Portable\v4.5\Microsoft.Portable.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
>
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.4\NuGet.targets(97,5): error : Unable to resolve 'd:\a\3\s\portableextensibility\portableextensibility.csproj' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1'. [d:\a\3\s\dotnetcompatibility.sln] C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.4\NuGet.targets(97,5): error : Unable to resolve 'd:\a\3\s\portablelibrary\portablelibrary.csproj' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1'. [d:\a\3\s\dotnetcompatibility.sln]   Generating MSBuild file d:\a\3\s\mainconsole\obj\mainconsole.csproj.nuget.g.props.   Generating MSBuild file d:\a\3\s\mainconsole\obj\mainconsole.csproj.nuget.g.targets.   Writing lock file to disk. Path: d:\a\3\s\mainconsole\obj\project.assets.json  Restore failed in 37.7 sec for d:\a\3\s\mainconsole\mainconsole.csproj.
>        Errors in d:\a\3\s\business\business.csproj
>         Unable to resolve 'd:\a\3\s\portablelibrary\portablelibrary.csproj' for '.NETStandard,Version=v1.1'.
>        Errors in d:\a\3\s\mainconsole\mainconsole.csproj
>         Unable to resolve 'd:\a\3\s\portableextensibility\portableextensibility.csproj' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1'.
>         Unable to resolve 'd:\a\3\s\portablelibrary\portablelibrary.csproj' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1'.

[image]

Comment: does `dotnet build` work on your local machine? I believe it doesn't.

Comment: It works. as I think? I copied portable from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\Portable` to `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.4\Microsoft\Portable`

Comment: So in this case, `msbuild` (commandline) and `dotnet build` both works.

Comment: you'd have to script that copy for the build servers as well.. msbuild should work automatically on the build servers without copying

Comment: @MartinUllrich, Yes I agreed. However MSBuild fails, too.

Comment: @MartinUllrich, is there any way to configure on Bamboo, as things things I mentioned in my answer. (Hosting Agent VS 2017, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the corrected configuration:

**Build Definition**

[image]

**Queue options**

[image]

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since the solution contains PCL libraries which currently cannot be built using the `dotnet` cli, the project has to be built through `msbuild` instead of the `dotnet` based commands.

Comment: just in case if you know about, is there any way to configure Quest agent `Hosted 2017` in bamboo. because I check in Team service, too, fails for `Hosted` agent.